# Lefalet markes from MySQL database with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, leaflet

I'm trying to add Lefalet Map that is JavaScript based to my HTML/PHP website.

Adding the MAP with HTML

```
echo "<div id='skijegern'></div>";
```

Easy.

Runned by Javacript like this

```
<script>
  var map = L.map('skijegern').setView([63.36601, 10.21204], 13);
  L.tileLayer('https://api.maptiler.com/maps/basic/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=dVhthbXQs3EHCi0XzzkL',{
    attribution:
    '<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
  }).addTo(map);
  //var marker = L.marker([14.0940, 120.6890]).addTo(map);
  var city = L.markerClusterGroup();
  // var Points = $.getJSON("get_location.php", function(data) {     
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var new_location = new L.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lon);
      var place = data[i].Details;
      var marker = new L.Marker(new_location, {
        title: place
      });
      var message = 'Demo: ' +place;
      marker.bindPopup(message);
      city.addLayer(marker);
    }

  map.addLayer(city);
</script>
```

So far so good, but it does not add Markers.

My JSON encode looks like this:

```
$sqls=mysqli_query($dbSQLi,"SELECT * FROM poster");
$data=array();
while($roww= mysqli_fetch_array($sqls)){
    $data[] = array("lat"=>$roww["gps_lat"], "lon"=>$roww["gps_long"], "Details"=>$roww['nr']);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

It gives data like this:

```
[
    {"lat":"63.36601","lon":"10.21204","Details":"1"},
    {"lat":"63.38334","lon":"10.19244","Details":"2"},
    {"lat":"63.39169","lon":"10.21045","Details":"3"},
    {"lat":"63.40088","lon":"10.18628","Details":"4"}
```

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you debugged the variables generated in the loop to determine if they are as you would expect? By that I refer to the code after `json_encode($data)` - such as `console.log(data[i].lat)` etc?

Comment: and why have you got `echo json_encode($data);` twice?

Comment: The two echo of the json, i printed it to the HTML page just to check my results.

Found this in the Console when running the map, can this be the cause?
Uncaught TypeError: L.markerClusterGroup is not a function

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: L.markerClusterGroup is not a function` - suggests looking at the documentation closely - I've never used leaflet maps so can off no guidance there

Comment: What if I want to add multiple lines like this inside the JavaScript, can that be easy done from a PHP script to pull the variables?

var marker = L.marker([63.4306306, 10.2459504]).addTo(map);